# Problems when batch converting .aea files using ffmpeg

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, conversion, wav, atrac

I'm running into a problem when using a bash for loop to convert all .aea files in a directory using ffmpeg (in this case, to .wav). I'm using the following:

```
 for f in *.aea; do ffmpeg -i "$f" “${f%.aea}.wav"; done
```

I immediately receive:

```
>
>
```

And can issue no further commands. Conversion file-by-file using, e.g.:

```
 sudo ffmpeg -i "Track 19.aea" Track019.wav
```

works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your third quote is a typographic opening quote `“` instead of a standard typewriter `"`.

That could very well cause the problems you're experiencing, making Bash wait for you to enter a closing quote.

Comment: Thanks so much for this, slhck! That did it. Much appreciated.